# Selectively removing trailing string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I want to remove the last letter "O", except where is is part of the word "HELLO".

I've tried doing this:

Example:

```
a <- c("HELLO XO","DO HELLO","TWO XO","HO")
gsub("[^HELLO]O\\>","",a)

[1] "HELLO " " HELLO" "T " "HO"
```

but I want

```
"HELLO X" "D HELLO" "TW X" "H"
```

Comment: are you actally mean a word boundary or the last letter of a word? Do you want to remove `O` from `fO.BA` this string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing using the following pattern:

```
\b(?!HELLO\b)(\w+)O\b
```

This says to assert that the word `HELLO` does not appear as the word, and then captures everything up until the final `O`, should it occur.  Then, it replaces with that optional final `O` removed.

```
\b          - from the start of the word
(?!HELLO\b) - assert that the word is not HELLO
(\w+)O      - match a word ending in O, but don't capture final O
\b          - end of word
```

The capture group, if a match happens, will contain the entire word minus the final O.

**Code:**

```
a <- c("HELLO XO","DO HELLO","TWO XO","HO")
gsub("\\b(?!HELLO\\b)(\\w+)O\\b", "\\1", a, perl=TRUE)
[1] "HELLO X" "D HELLO" "TW X"    "H"
```

Note that we must Perl mode enabled (`perl=TRUE`) with `gsub` in order to use the negative lookahead.

### Demo

Comment: Did you not like my edit? Sorry, didn't mean to overstep!

Comment: @aaaidan Not a problem, you're right, it needs an explanation.

Comment: I would like it, could you explain it to me

Comment: I gave a more verbose explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex alternation operator `|`

```
a <- c("HELLO XO","DO HELLO","TWO XO","HO")
gsub("(HELLO)|O(?!\\S)", "\\1", a, perl=T)
# [1] "HELLO X" "D HELLO" "TW X"    "H"
```

`(HELLO)|O` this regex does two things,

1. First it captures all the `HELLO` string.
2. Matches all the remaining `0`'s which are not followed by a non-space character.

Comment: This is clever! Could you spell it out though?

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is nit correct.`[^HELLO]` means any character except `H`, `E`, `L` and `O`. But you need except only exactly `HELL` before `O`. So, you should use following expression:

```
a <- c("HELLO XO","DO HELLO","TWO XO","HO")
gsub("(?<!\\bHELL)O\\b", "", a, perl=TRUE)
```

Comment: Code only answers may solve the original problem, but some explanation of the solution makes for a much better answer. It can help others understand how to use your solution in similar situations.

Comment: @NigelRen I added some explanation. Is it better?

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- c("HELLO XO","DO HELLO","TWO XO","HO")

aa <- gsub("O","",a)
gsub("HELL", "HELLO",aa)
```

Comment: This isn't quite what the OP is looking for. This will remove O, and reinstate HELLOs, but it will also transform all HELL in the original input ito HELLO.

Answer (score 0):

A little lengthy, but you can try like this

```
a <- c("HELLO XO","DO HELLO","TWO XO","HO")
b <- lapply(a, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, " ")))
b
> b
[[1]]
[1] "HELLO" "XO"   

[[2]]
[1] "DO"    "HELLO"

[[3]]
[1] "TWO" "XO" 

[[4]]
[1] "HO"


c <- unlist(lapply(b, function(y) paste(ifelse( y == "HELLO", "HELLO", gsub("O", "", y)), collapse = " " )))
c

[1] "HELLO X" "D HELLO" "TW X"    "H"
```

Comment: step b is -> splitting the each string by space. step c --> for each split word, check if it's hello or not. Finally bind the split string again.

Comment: are you convinced with the approach?